# Finding $\text{cov}(X,Z) $ given $\text{cov}(X,Y) = 0.1$ and $\text{cov}(Y,Z) = 0.8$

Tags: probability, covariance

Given three random variables $X,Y, Z$, if $\text{cov}(X,Y) = 0.1$ and $\text{cov}(Y,Z) = 0.8$, is it possible that $\text{cov}(X,Z) = 0.7$?

I know how to solve the question if correlation is used instead of covariance (all the three variances are equal to 1). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How would you do it if it were correlation?

Comment: Well, you can get bounds on the covariance between a and c. Use that the covariance is a bilinear, symmetric and positive semi-definite form. You can employ, for instance, the direct definition or Sylvester criteria adapted for the positive semi-definite case (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_criterion). Correlation is just standardised covariance, so the procedure is the same.

Comment: See a similar question:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/726205/1231520

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. A covariance matrix of interest is

$$
 \begin{bmatrix} 
 1 & 0.1 & 0.7 \\
 0.1 & 1 & 0.8\\
 0.7 & 0.8 & \alpha \\
 \end{bmatrix}
 \quad
 $$

for $\alpha \ge 1.03$.

For $\alpha = 1.03$, the eigenvalues are

$[2.12820779, \, 0.900905553, \, 8.86656963 \text{e-04}],$

which are positive.

For $\alpha = 1.02$, they are

$[ 2.12338262, \, 0.90090392,\, -0.00428654]$;

hence, the matrix with $\alpha = 1.02$ is not positive semi-definite (one of its eigenvalues is negative) and cannot be a covariance matrix.

For given $a,b,c$ (the covariances), the matrix

$$
 \begin{bmatrix} 
 x & a & b \\
 a & y & c\\
 b & c & z \\
 \end{bmatrix}
 \quad
 $$

is a covariance matrix iff $x, y, z$ (the variances) satisfy the following conditions:

$$x,y,z \ge 0$$
$$xy\ge a^2,yz\ge c^2, xz\ge b^2$$
$$x(yz-c^2)-a(az-cb)+b(ac-by)\ge 0.$$

Moreover, when $a, b$ are given, you can find the minimum and maximum values of $W$, $\text{cov}(X,Z)$, for which the matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
 x & a & b \\
 a & y & W\\
 b & W & z \\
 \end{bmatrix}
 \quad$$

remains a covariance matrix using semi-definite programming:

$$\text{min/max} \, W$$
subject to

$$
 \begin{bmatrix} 
 x & a & b \\
 a & y & W\\
 b & W & z \\
 \end{bmatrix} \succeq \bf{0}
 \quad
$$
$$ W \in \mathbb R. $$

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response! I have a follow-up question. The diagonal of a covariance matrix consists of the variances. Why do we assume that var(X,X) = 1, and var(Y,Y) = 1?

Comment: @Vanessa When all the variances are 1, the matrix cannot be a covariance matrix (or a correlation matrix); the eigenvalues are $[2.11380268, \, 0.90090068, \, -0.01470336]$. By a direct search, I found out that for the variances 1, 1, and $ \alpha \ge 1.03 $ the matrix becomes a covariance matrix. I tried to find the nearest case to 1, 1, 1. Other values can be chosen. For example, when the variances are set to 2, 1, and 1, the matrix is again a covariance matrix because the eigenvalues are $[2.52123096, \, 1.38359548, \, 0.09517356].$

Comment: @Vanessa I just added more details.

Comment: Thanks so much @Amir, I understand better now. How about the case where the variances of all 3 random variables are not provided? In other words, var(x) and var(y) and var(z) are unknown. Would we still be able to check if cov(X,Z) = 0.7?

Comment: @Vanessa All the elements of the covariance matrix are related to each other and cannot be analyzed independently as the matrix must be psd. In your case, you can see that 0.7 is acceptable for some variances and not for some other values. So if they are unknown, for 0.7 the answer is both YES and NO in light of that there are some feasible variances for both cases (see the examples).

Comment: @Vanessa if you find the answer useful, you can accept it to make the question more visible.